# Docker compose service needs to wait for docker-entrypoint-initdb.d scripts to import

Tags: mysql, docker, docker-compose

I have a docker-compose service that's configured to *depend on* a mysql server. The problem is that I'm initializing the database when the service first boots, so my service not only needs to wait for the mysql instance to be ready for connections, but it needs to wait for the data import.

```
myservice:
  depends_on:
    db:
      condition: service_healthy
```

`service_completed_successfully` doesn't work, `myservice` never boots. `service_healthy` works but I don't see any way to ensure the data import process has completed. It's a 75MB sql file so it takes a minute to fully load.

Most health checks just ping mysql, which means `myservice` starts booting before the data is loaded.

```
version: '3.7'

services:
  db:
    image: mysql:8.0.33
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: 'test'
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: 'test'
    ports:
    - 3306:3306
    expose:
    - 3306
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "mysqladmin", "ping", "-h", "localhost", "-u", "root", "-p$$MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD"]
      timeout: 20s
      retries: 10
    volumes:
    - ./sql/test.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/test.sql
    - mysql:/var/lib/mysql
```

Docker starts booting `myservice` before the data has imported, and once the data import *does finish* docker reboots mysql:

```
db_1  | 2023-05-11T18:36:01.172885Z 0 [System] [MY-010910] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete (mysqld 8.0.33)  MySQL Community Server - GPL.
db_1  | 2023-05-11 18:36:01+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Temporary server stopped
db_1  |
db_1  | 2023-05-11 18:36:01+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: MySQL init process done. Ready for start up.
db_1  |
db_1  | 2023-05-11T18:36:01.769092Z 0 [Warning] [MY-011068] [Server] The syntax '--skip-host-cache' is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use SET GLOBAL host_cache_size=0 instead.
db_1  | 2023-05-11T18:36:01.770116Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.33) starting as process 1
db_1  | 2023-05-11T18:36:01.776905Z 1 [System] [MY-013576] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has started.
db_1  | 2023-05-11T18:36:01.904675Z 1 [System] [MY-013577] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has ended.
db_1  | 2023-05-11T18:36:02.168020Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010068] [Server] CA certificate ca.pem is self signed.
db_1  | 2023-05-11T18:36:02.168064Z 0 [System] [MY-013602] [Server] Channel mysql_main configured to support TLS. Encrypted connections are now supported for this channel.
db_1  | 2023-05-11T18:36:02.172087Z 0 [Warning] [MY-011810] [Server] Insecure configuration for --pid-file: Location '/var/run/mysqld' in the path is accessible to all OS users. Consider choosing a different directory.
db_1  | 2023-05-11T18:36:02.193999Z 0 [System] [MY-011323] [Server] X Plugin ready for connections. Bind-address: '::' port: 33060, socket: /var/run/mysqld/mysqlx.sock
db_1  | 2023-05-11T18:36:02.194118Z 0 [System] [MY-010931] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections. Version: '8.0.33'  socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'  port: 3306  MySQL Community Server - GPL.
```

Which interferes with connections from my app.

I don't *have* to import data this way - I could just manually boot mysql and run the import myself, then boot the rest, but I'd like to automate it if I can.

Comment: It's not clear exactly what the problem is. `service_healthy` is what you are likely looking for. You need to add a `HEALTHCHECK` to the mysql server container. For example, run a CLI query to determine if the image has completed the import and return exit code `0`, otherwise `non-zero`

Comment: The problem is that the current healthcheck returns true and allows the other service to boot despite the fact that the import is still running. I need to somehow ensure the import has finished in the health check. I could maybe run a count of how many tables exist but I don't know how to do that in this context. That's what I need help with

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example `docker-compose.yml` for `MySQL` with a `HEALTHCHECK` which counts the number of tables that exist in the database:

```yaml
version: '3'
services:
  mysql:
    image: mysql:latest
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: test
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: test
    healthcheck:
      test:
        - CMD-SHELL
        - |
          mysql -h localhost -u root -p$${MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD} \
          --database $${MYSQL_DATABASE} -e 'SHOW TABLES' | \
          [ $$(wc -l) -gt 10 ]
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 5s
      retries: 3
```

Here the test `$(wc -l)` will look for the number of lines from the `mysql` table count query, and then test if the count is greater than `10`. If so, it will return `0` indicating the `HEALTHCHECK` has passed, otherwise `1` to indicate the container is not ready.

You can check the status of a container's health using:

```bash
$ docker inspect --format "{{json .State.Health }}" [container_name] | jq '.'
{
  "Status": "healthy",
  "FailingStreak": 0,
  "Log": [
    {
      "Start": "2023-05-11T15:36:55.375004326-07:00",
      "End": "2023-05-11T15:36:55.433787068-07:00",
      "ExitCode": 0,
      "Output": "mysql: [Warning] Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.\n"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: I had to add a $ to escape `$(wc -l)` but after that it appears to work properly!

Comment: @helion3 so this works well for you? I have a similar issue where my MYSQL database is being imported the first time it is ran. My only problem with that is I will forever have to wait 20s or so for my other containers to start even though it is unneeded. But I don't think there's a way for Docker to only wait the first time it is ran.